# Wound on the head of my goldfish

Tags: health, fish, injury, skin-condition, goldfish

I had two gold fishes and a few days ago I noticed my other fish was sitting at the bottom of his tank and struggling to to get to the top (swimming to the top and automatically sinking down). I had no idea what was wrong because he wasn’t acting that way the day before, so I panicked and did a full water change thinking it might improve and after my fish being in the water for a few hours he was still sitting on the bottom until he died.

My other fish now has a wound on the top of his head and I’m not sure what it’s from; all help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please post the last readings of your watertest PH-AMMONIA-NITRITE,how big is your tank is it heated and filtrated,for how long has your tank been running and is it properly cycled.

Comment: I am having this same problem now. I just had another fish die and now the other one has this weird sore. What did you do to help the fish heal?

Answer (score 1):

Update: The wound is almost gone and healing well.