# Goldfish problem

Tags: goldfish

[image]Hey guys any idea what’s wrong with this poor guy he’s acting pretty normal but he has this big red spot/bump between his eyes and he has brown around some of the white on him. The white and the jagged fins are because he was attacked by another fish but I separated them. But he keeps getting worse I’ve been using melafix but it does not seem to be doing anything
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: @BobaFit just added some!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wound on the head of my goldfish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29069/wound-on-the-head-of-my-goldfish)

Comment: @AllisonC no I’m not sure what I can do to help the fish I did a water change but it’s not helping

Comment: can you please post the readings of your latest watertest PH-NITRITE-AMMONIA,is your tank properly cycled https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm.the thing to do right now is to add 0,3% aquarium salt to your tank and to stop feeding the fish.i need the information to answer your question,it might be too late to save the fish you have now but it is not too late to save your next ones.to get to 0,3% aquarium salt you use 3 grams salt to 10 litres of aquariumwater(salt is used to protect against nitrite poisoning in fishtanks).